# (HtmlSpanner)How would I get or parse the content from an Html that has a css source code in android? I already tried the html spanner

Tags: android, html, android-edittext, textview

Why do I need to parse the whole source code?

*The source code was generated from an **IOS** with its Text Field, in order for **IOS** to upload the content with its style it needs to be generated like this(**html_string**) along with the auto-generated **CSS Style** and the problem is when the **Android** needs to view this data, it needs to be parsed to see the content and I tried the **Html.fromHtml()** function from android but it is limited on it its functionality so I found this **HtmlSpanner Library** and it also supports with **css** styles below is my following results.

**Html.fromHtml** supports:

p,
ul,
li,
div,
span,
strong,
b,
br,
em,
cite,
dfn,
i,
big,
small,
font,
blockquote,
tt,
a,
u,
del,
s,
strike,
sup,
sub,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
img

**this is the html source code with css:**

```
    String html_string = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\"><title></title><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\"><style type=\"text/css\">p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 12.0px 0.0px; line-height: 15.0px;  'Times New Roman'; color: #626262; -webkit-text-stroke: #626262}span.s1 { font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; ; font-kerning: none}span.s2 { font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; ; font-kerning: none}span.s3 { font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; ; font-kerning: none}</style></head><body><p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">1. The team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should only be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improved</span></p><p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">1. Th</span><span class=\"s2\">e team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should o</span><span class=\"s1\">nly be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improved</span></p><p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">1. The team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box</span><span class=\"s3\">should only be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Po</span><span class=\"s1\">ints could be improved</span></p><p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">1. The te</span><span class=\"s2\">am switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should only be a</span><span class=\"s1\">s tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improved</span></p><p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">1. The team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description</span><span class=\"s3\">box should only be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improv</span><span class=\"s1\">ed raffish</span></p></body></html>";
```

**String** spanner_result = "" + (new HtmlSpanner()).fromHtml(html_string);

**EditText** myEditText;

myEditText.setText((new HtmlSpanner()).fromHtml(spanner_result ));

**EditText Results:**

1. The team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should only be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improved
2. Th e team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should o nly be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improved
3. The team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should only be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Po ints could be improved
4. The te am switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should only be a s tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improved
5. The team switcher should look like the project switcher. 2. The task description box should only be as tall as it needs to be. 3. Alignment of the Unassigned | Due Date | Story Points could be improv ed raffish

I'm actually amazed what the library do to the string it clears out the source code that is not needed and shows the content but my problem is it did not show the style format of the content.

If it is not possible is there another method to resolve this issue? and if it is possible could you help me or give some advise to follow the right track.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple solution I can offer you is using a `WebView` and loading the HTML in it. Like this:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"/>
```

html_string is the HTML String you provided in your question.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html_string, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what I'm I trying to do is to load the content in the EditText so that I can view the data and to be able to edit it when needed. Can I extract the content of the html through webview? sorry for asking I'm not so familiar with webview.

Comment: So you basically mean extracting the text out of the html? this is a bit more complicated but I have found a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180926/htmlspannerhow-would-i-get-or-parse-the-content-from-an-html-that-has-a-css-so/48182052?noredirect=1#comment83344246_48182052

Comment: Yes like getting what is inside the <body>content.....</body> the HtmlSpanner can retrieve it like what is inside my EditText Results. That is the result of extracting the content of html_string using the HtmlSpanner library. The problem is, it is not reading the style so some of the text are bold and it is only showing plain text.